# MongoDB Insert value to the DB from Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Currently, can not put "insertOne" due to maybe current jar.
*I am using "mongo-java-driver-3.12.2.jar" on IntelliJ.

Would you mind telling me what jar file does include "insertOne" ?

What I'm trying to do is below.

```
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                    "mongodb+srv://xxxx");

            try(MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)){
                MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
                MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
                Document query = new Document("_id", new ObjectId("objectID xxxx"));
                Document result = collection.find(query).iterator().next();

                Document test = new Document("_id","ObjectID xxxx");
                test.append("test4","test is 4");
                query.insertOne(test);  --> Currently the "insertOne" is not recognized..


                System.out.println("Test3: "+result.getString("test3"));
```

Comment: You are trying to perform an `insertOne` on a `Document` object. That doesn't make sense. You insert on a `MongoCollection`. See the guide here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/#insert-a-document

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not find that. In terms of "Collection.insertOne", this is used in case of adding. what about updating the existing one?  I could not find that description.

Comment: Here are some tutorials for doing CRUD (create, read, update and delete) operations using the Java and MongoDB: [Quick Start: Java and MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-java-and-mongodb--starting-and-setup).

Answer (score 2):

I see you're trying to do `query.insertOne(test)`, but you defined `query` as being a `Document`. However, the `insertOne` method is defined on a `MongoCollection`, not on a `Document`, see [the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-)

Instead, try: `collection.insertOne(test)`

Comment: Thank you, I could not find what you attached. Now I got it !